# C# SMTP message transfer to recipient through MX Record

Tags: c#, email, smtp, mx-record

I know there many articles on web regarding sending emails from code/C# and I have read many of them before posting here, but I still don't see a clear picture of how to implement my requirements:

**Scenario:**
My application on **mydomain.com** receives a request to send some kind of email (**from:** someone@mydomain.com, **to:** someone@gmail.com/anyother.com).
I need to make some manipulations on email content.
After I modified a message, I need to send it **directly** to recipient.

Under **directly** to recipient I mean that I want to send it to recipient by our servers and not using some kind of SMTP service/relay.

So as I understand I can install some SMTP software on our servers and send using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` to our server and it will deliver it to recipients using SMTP Relay or some other way that coded inside that software...but, I would like to make it without using SMTP Server software...

Till now I found that I need to discover MX record for recipients domain, so let's say I found MX record for gmail.com (gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com), but how do I send email to that MX Record from my own C# code?

Does `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` suitable for this task?
Where I can find examples of how to do it?

From my previous expirience with SmtpClient, I need to provide SMTP server address (optionaly port), credentials, but in my case, of course I do not have credentials and I'm not sure how to get the correct port (does all servers from MX records has port 25?).

Thanks!

Comment: Why in the world would you want to reinvent an SMTP relay?

Comment: @DanWilson Mostly because I want to understand the topic better, and after that I will finally decide what to use and how...but I have some holes in my head regarding how the things work.